# How do I access sales_flat_shipment_track.track_number in older versions of Magento (1.5)

Tags: magento-1.5

I've written a module for Magento that works fine on newer versions (tested on 1.8 and 1.9), but of course now I face a customer who is running an ancient 1.5. This causes trouble, since it seems that the table `sales_flat_shipment_track` does not have a column `track_number`. I assume the schema was changed at some point, but what is the right way to access this information in older installations of the application?

Not sure how important it is, but the code that is triggering the error is:

```
<?php
class Foo_Bar_Model_Carrier extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
  public function isTrackingAvailable() {
    return true;
  }

  public function getTrackingInfo($tracking) {
    /** @var $trackInfo Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Track */
    $trackInfo = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->load($tracking, 'track_number');
    /** @var $track Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result_Status */
    $track = Mage::getModel('shipping/tracking_result_status');
    $track->setUrl($trackInfo->getTitle())
      ->setTracking($trackInfo->getTrackNumber())
      ->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    return $track;
  }

  // snip ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. It would seem that the column is called `number` instead of `track_number`. I have modified my code to this now:

```
  public function getTrackingInfo($tracking) {
    // Because: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118072/how-do-i-access-sales-flat-shipment-track-track-number-in-older-versions-of-mage
    $mage_version = Mage::getVersionInfo();
    if ($mage_version['major'] == 1 && $mage_version['minor'] < 6) {
      $track_column = 'number';
    } else {
      $track_column = 'track_number';
    }
    /** @var $trackInfo Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Track */
    $trackInfo = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->load($tracking, $track_column);
    /** @var $track Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result_Status */
    $track = Mage::getModel('shipping/tracking_result_status');
    $track->setUrl($trackInfo->getTitle())
      ->setTracking($trackInfo->getTrackNumber())
      ->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    return $track;
  }
```